# a good licence for a CMS?

Tags: cms, open-source, licenses

Going over quite a bit of Open Source licenses on [opensource.org](http://opensource.org) I am still not very clear which one I should aim for. What I want the license to do is the following.

1. Open Source license
2. Initial Developer(s)/Contributer(s) are to be credited and all copyright notices, credit notices as well as trademark and/or patten notices to remain in the "Source Code" and in no way may be altered.
3. Any software based of original "Source Code" are to be licensed under the same license as the original source and all source code "must" be available to end-user. Also any copy or re-distribution and/or fork must contain original copyright notices by Initial Developer(s)/Contributer(s)
4. The license is royalty-free for non-commercial use, non-profit organization use and /or any personal use.
5. The source code may be licensed under commercial license for commercial use, but must be done so with first acknowledge the Original Developer and for royalty. Even so any commercial license "may not" prevent the Initial Developer from continuing of licensing, development and distribution of "original Source Code" for personal, non-commercial and non-profit use under the original license and without any fee.
6. Commercial license can't and shall not effect or hold any of "original Source Code" that may prevent the re-use of the original "Source Code" by 3rd party developers, re-distributer and or forked projects.
7. The license applies internationally

I wish to allow the use of the software for commercial/small-business use but for a small royalty. However I do not want to get screwed into having that commercial institution the "sole" holder of the "original Source Code". I still need to make sure I the Initial Developer and any Contributers retain the "source code" as there own and not any 3rd party.

So what would be the best suggestions for a license close to the 7 points that I made.

Comment: Flagging off-topic. Belongs at [programmers.se](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Su' I do not see how this would not fit into Web Master section, as I am talking about a WEB APP in which case a CMS, I did not say desktop CMS did i? And I am not asking about Programming, but license. And I honestly do not like all it know f&&*s. So if you can't tell a difference between a question related to programming and licensing then don't post. As I see absolutely "0" CODE OR QUESTIONS ABOUT CODE

Comment: You're correct you aren't asking about programming(would more more likely be [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), actually), but it's still a programming-*related* issue. This site is for questions concerning the [operation of websites](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq). Programmers.se is for questions about [software licensing](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq). I had nothing to do with those FAQs, and regardless what you might've chosen to extrapolate from my neutral, factual statement above, I'm just trying to get your question where it'd receive the best attention.